# Can't change css property after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call an trying to add a class to a DOM element, and then change a value of a property of that class.

I can add the class, but not changing the attribute.

```
<script>
function load_to_be_analysed_count() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'experiments/to_be_analysed/count',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            // data is the number of experiments to be analysed, returned from server
            if (data >= 0) {
                $('#new_experiments').addClass('badger');
                console.log($('.badger').css('content'));  // DEBUG
                $('.badger').css('content', data);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#login-language').html('<p>An error ocurred</p>'); // TODO: just for debug. Maybe console.log
        }
    });
    if ($('#new_experiment').hasClass('badger')) {
        $('.badger')
    }
}
$(function () {
    load_to_be_analysed_count()
})
</script>
```

**HTML before:**

```
<i id="new_experiments" class="fa fa-bell fa-2x icon-grey"></i>
```

When I load the page, Inspector display `none` when `console.log($('.badger').css('content'));  // DEBUG` is reached.

In Inspector, I can see the above HTML changed to

**HTML after:**

```
<i id="new_experiments" class="fa fa-bell fa-2x icon-grey badger" style=""></i>
```

**CSS:**

```
i#new_experiments {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
.badger:after{
    content: "50";
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 2rem;
    top: -0.2rem;
    right: 0.2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: `content` goes in the pseudo class, which you can't do inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a new style tag with the given content

```
    success: function(data) {
        // data is the number of experiments to be analysed, returned from server
        if (data >= 0) {
            $('#new_experiments').addClass('badger');
            console.log($('.badger').css('content'));  // DEBUG
            $('head').append('<style>.badger::after{content:"' + data + '"}</style>');
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks @Musa. I just made minor adjusts: `$('head').append('<style>.badger::after{content:"' + data + '"}</style>');`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/21709814#21709814) you can't access :before and :after in jQuery as they are not part of the DOM. The *content* attribute only works with those two pseudo classes.

You have to change your structure I think. A possibility would be to create an Element that has position: relative/absolute without using :after/:before and then do something like:

```
$('.badger').html(data);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have explained. This should do it

Comment: This solves badger problem, but `::after` is required to correctly render  `fa-bel` icon + badger. But thanks anyway.